# NDSolve on arbitrary domain

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I used NDSolve to obtain numerical solutions to a Poisson equation employing Dirichlet BCs on the unit circle using the following commands

```
b0=1;
k=3;

usoldisk = NDSolveValue[{
             D[u[x,y],x,x]+D[u[x,y],y,y] == -k^2 u[x, y] + k b0, 
             DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u, {x,y} \[Element] Disk[]
           ]
```

I want to solve the same equation on arbitrary domains with boundaries defined by parametric equations. For example I would like to solve the equation on an y-elongated disk with its center located at (1,0). I assume that I have to use `ParametricRegion`. However I don't know what kind of modifications should I make in `usoldisk`.

Also another problem: Can we obtain a fit of the numerical result in terms of the coordinates $x$, $y$?

Comment: What if you use something like `DiscretizeRegion[ParametricRegion[{1 + r Cos[t], 2 r Sin[t]}, {{r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}}]]`?

Comment: @J. M. Ok that's reasonable, but how I proceed from this point ??

Comment: ...then replace the `Disk[]` with... that.

Comment: @J. M. You're right! thank you... What do you think about the fitting? Is Mathematica capable? We need to make computations using u. For example I need its Gradient.

Comment: `Grad` can be directly used on `InterpolatingFunction`…

Comment: @xzczd The result is not smooth. If we plot the derivative there "spikes". They can be minimized by densing the grid but they cannot be eliminated. How can we smooth the derivative? I thought that I need some kind of fitting...

Comment: Have you tried more `PlotPoints`?

Comment: @xzczd Sorry, the problem of the "non-smoothness" occurs when taking the second derivative. The first is smooth. Yes I tried more `PlotPoints`. The same problem...

Comment: Try a smaller `"MaxCellMeasure"`

Comment: @xzczd it does not work... Only `MeshRefinementFunction` improves the outcome, but the "spikes" are still there... much smaller but still there..

Comment: Without more specific example it's hard to answer your question, you'd better start a new question. BTW in my experience, fitting isn't the correct way to go.